# Should we ask people with Steam/Steam integrated game issues for their Steam profiles?

Tags: support

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/210321/the-tf2-trading-only-shows-me-a-couple-items-when-i-have-tons

Aytimothy asked the OP for his Steam profile to further troubleshoot the issue. Should we ask for "personal" info when trying to fix the issue? Or should we just keep asking the OP to clarify what exactly the problem is. It could be potentially useful to see his profile but asking for personal information, especially on a Q&A site may be problematic.

Comment: Given that the purpose of questions here is to help *everyone*, I don't think focusing on a specific user's profile is the way to go.

Comment: @Sterno I agree with your viewpoint, I just want to know what we officially allow on the site and disallow on the site in regards to asking for "personal" information.

Comment: Personally, I don't think that user has provided enough information to even begin to troubleshoot his issue.

Comment: @Frank I think it's worded poorly but I have a few "leads" regarding why he may have issues trading. With a profile we could resolve the issue much quicker, at the same time questions should be applicable to the masses, not to one particular individual's issue.

Comment: Yes, agreed.  Questions should be applicable to the masses.  What we have, however, is a rather poorly worded question, without enough to go off to solve the issue.  This could actually just be a straight up user error.

Comment: Relevant meta discussion: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10019/whats-the-sites-policy-on-personal-details-in-questions-answers-comments-etc